# Как ускорить поиск в ширину?

Tags: c++, графы

Имеется программа, выполняющая обход в ширину в ориентированном графе. Граф в памяти предствален в виде матрицы. Граф читается из файла in.txt в виде

4 4 -число вершин и ребер

0 1

1 2

2 3 - пути между вершинами

```
#include <vector>
#include <locale.h>
#include <queue>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <set>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <ctime>


using namespace std;
UINT breadthFirstSearch(vector<vector<UINT>> &graph, UINT begin, UINT vertex, UINT n)
{
   queue<UINT> q;
   q.push(begin);

   set<int> gray;

   while (!q.empty())
   {
      UINT i = 0;

      q.pop();
      gray.insert(q.front());

      if (q.front() == vertex)
         return 1;

      while (i < n)
      {
         if (graph[q.front()][i])
            q.push(i);

         i++;
      }

      if (q.empty()) return 0;
   }
}

void main()
{
   UINT one = 0, two = 0;
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

   ifstream get_content("in.txt");

   UINT vertex, edge;

   get_content >> edge;
   get_content >> vertex;

   vector<vector<UINT>> graph;

   graph.assign(vertex, vector<UINT>(vertex));;

   UINT i = 0;

   while (i < edge)
   {
      UINT one, two;
      get_content >> one;
      get_content >> two;
      graph[one][two] = 1;

      i++;
   }

   printf_s("Введите две вершины: ");

   cin >> one;
   cin >> two;

   set<UINT> gray;
   set <UINT>black;

   unsigned int start_time = clock(); 

   UINT b = breadthFirstSearch(graph, one, two, vertex);

   unsigned int end_time = clock(); 
   unsigned int search_time = end_time - start_time;

   printf_s("%d", search_time);

   b ? printf_s("Путь есть\n") : printf_s("Пути нет\n");

   return;
}
```

Тестирование показало, что данный код работает в 2 раза медленнее поиска в глубину.
Как ускорить работу программы?(нужно также исправление в коде)

Comment: удалите переменную `gray` - будет быстрее.

Comment: два раза проверять пустоту в цикле это лишнее `if (q.empty()) return 0;`

Comment: Переменная `gray` не используется. Следовательно вы в ациклическом направленном графе перебираете некоторые вершины много раз. А в циклическом вообще зациклитесь. Исправьте алгоритм, измерять производительность можно только у правильных алгоритмов.

Comment: Измерять время `clock` можно только если время работы программы измеряется десятками секунд. Иначе разрешаюшая способность `clock` не досаточна. Добавьте результаты замеров в вопрос, пожалуйста.